# PHP user-defined function that doesn't return nothing but "echo" only

Tags: php

Strange question.

I have this code:

```
function createNumber()
{
    // other code initialisizing $base and $arr
    $result = checkArray($base, $arr);
    echo $result; // <- this doesn't print nothing
} // function

function checkArray($value,$array)
{
    $result = '';
    if (in_array($value,$array))
    {
        $value = $value+1;
        checkArray($value,$array);
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $value;
        //return $result;
        //echo $result; <- this doesn't print nothing
    }
    echo $result; // <- this print the right value
    //return $result; // <- this seems doesn't return nothing
}
```

If in `checkArray` I uncomment the `return $result row` and I comment `echo $result` it prints correctly the $result.

Otherwise, it **seems** that doesn't return nothing (i.e. the createNumber function doesnt' print nothing.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try var_dumping the results

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you don't return `$result` then `createNumber` can't echo it.

Comment: where you are assigning values for $base, $arr

Comment: `checkArray()` isn't explicitly returning anything, so it will return a `null` by default, and you're assigning that `null` to `$result` and echoing that

Comment: Are you running the function `createNumber()`? If you so you need to `return $result` in `checkArray` for it to echo the result.

Comment: @superphonic yes, I'm running the createNumber . If i put return in checkArray and echo in createNumber... echo nothing.